# InvalidRequestException(why:No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with "equals" operator)

Tags: java, cassandra

I have created one keyspace and created the column family with some column names. And also added the records in that keyspace programmatically. Now I am going to add one more coulmn in that keysapce and added the new records. It was success... But while searching with that new column field value with equals operator.. I am getting the following exception `me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with "equals" operator)`

I think there are the rows which does not have the new column field... Is That make an issue?..  Could you please anyone help me to how to solve this problem?.... In Normal Relational database we can add null values to the existing records if any new column is added in the table... Is there anyway like that we can do with cassandra to solve this problem?.... My Final Result should be I can able to search the records with the new column field....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes...the reason you get exception is the newly added column in not `indexed` to perform equality or similar operations ; while altering column family you have to write e.g.

```
column_metadata = [{column_name : 'username',
    validation_class : UTF8Type,
    index_name : 'username_idx',
    index_type : 0}]
```

so your final alter query would be like this

```
UPDATE COLUMN FAMILY your_CF_name with column_type = 'Standard'
      and comparator = 'UTF8Type'
      and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
      and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
      and column_metadata = [
        {column_name : 'your_all_existing_columns',
        validation_class : your_all_existing_validation_class,
        index_name : 'user_defined_name',
        index_type : 0},
           .
           .
           .
    {column_name : 'your_new_additional_column',
        validation_class : your_validation_class,
        index_name : 'user_defined_name',
        index_type : 0}];
```